# mysql 5.6 gtid replication: is log_slave_updates required?

Tags: mysql

I've read the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-gtids-howto.html) saying log_slave_updates is required.  It makes sense for a general promotion situation.

But is that really still required for something you're intending to be a read only slave that will never get promoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you must set it when using gtid, **otherwise mysql won't start**, providing you the following error:

```
[ERROR] --gtid-mode=ON or UPGRADE_STEP_1 or UPGRADE_STEP_2 requires 
--log-bin and --log-slave-updates
```

The slave requires its own executed binary logs in order to auto-position itself in the case of a stop (for example, if it crashes) or a master change (the hardware on the master fails without a possibility of a fix and another slave is promoted as the new slave), even if it is not going to be a master itself never. Although I suppose that can be controlled exclusively in-memory when running, I would bet it needs its own binary logs as a failsafe in case of a crash.

You may think that that is a lot of trouble, but it is **a small burden in exchange for not having to deal with binlog files and binlog pos addresses anymore**. Also, binary logs on the slave was always a good idea. **You can still purge them automatically with `expire-logs-days/max-binlog-size`** if the size is the problem. And **with group-commit in 5.6, the performance penalty should be minimal**. The other thing why I did not used `log_slave_updates` before (checking that no writes have been done on the slaves) can now be controlled with `gtid_executed` values.

In a nutshell, set it up, and do not worry on most cases.

Comment: Just for anyone else who happens by here, for our workload `log_slave_updates` imposes a penalty of around 10% to replication performance, which could be a dealbreaker for some.